# is it possible to set different mongodb replica set readPreference for different calls, on the same connection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Use case**

I'd like to be able to read from the 'nearest' mongodb node when it is just a read operation, but to be able to make transactions (which require a 'primary' readPreference).

Currently I have to set readPreference="primary" on the connection, to be able to make transactions.

I did try to set readPreferene to "nearest" on the connection, and when making the transaction calls involving the session to set it to primary, but didn't work (not that I ever found any documentation saying it's supposed to work).

```
mongoose.model("cars").create([{name: "subaruo"], {
  session: session,
  readPreference: "primary",
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to specify the readPreference="primary" in the call to session.startTransaction()

```
session.startTransaction({
  readPreference: "primary",
});
```